# django serializer y paginación

Tags: django, serialización, paginación

¿Como lograr paginar la respuesta de la clase con serializador?
Sólo necesito paginar esta clase, no paginación general(settings)

La query es dinamica según la refcat que ponga el usuario.

¿Alguna ayuda?
Aquí mi programa.

serializers.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models.predio import Predio


class PredioSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Predio
        fields = ('refcat', 'id', 'destino')
```

api.py (vista)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render
from .models.predio import Predio
from .serializers import PredioSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets


class PredioList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Predio.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PredioSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        refcat = self.request.query_params.get('refcat')
        return Predio.objects.filter(refcat__startswith=refcat)
```

urls.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from rest_framework import routers
from .api import PredioList

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'predio', PredioList, base_name='predio')

urlpatterns = [
    # include(router.urls))
    url(r'^api/(?P<refcat>.+)/$', PredioList.as_view({'get': 'list'}))
]
```

La aplicación funciona con query dinámica, funciona correctamente, pero debido la inmensidad de la BD, necesito paginar resultados en paginas de 2 o 3.

lLa respuesta que ahora me saca, sería (según refcat incompleto de entrada):

```
[{"destino":"A","refcat":"080010101000003320901900000012","id":913},{"destino":"A","refcat":"080010101000003320901900000011","id":6562},{"destino":"A","refcat":"080010101000003320005000000000","id":22776},{"destino":"A","refcat":"080010101000003320007000000000","id":10231},{"destino":"A","refcat":"080010101000003320901900000010","id":37714},{"destino":"I","refcat":"080010101000003320002000000000","id":32171},{"destino":"A","refcat":"080010101000003320006000000000","id":1249},{"destino":"A","refcat":"080010101000003320003000000000","id":13884},{"destino":"A","refcat":"080010101000003320901900000009","id":10097},{"destino":"A","refcat":"080010101000003320008000000000","id":44054},{"destino":"A","refcat":"080010101000003320004000000000","id":1},{"destino":"A","refcat":"080010101000003320013000000000","id":19833}]
```

Esto necesitaría paginarlo ya que podría ser muy, muy extenso el resultado.

¿ Alguna solución ?
he rebuscado pero no encuentro exactamente lo que necesito o no lo se interpretar.

Gracias!!!

Comment: Ya leíste [esto](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/)? está en la misma documentación de Django Rest Framework

Comment: Si, la leí mil veces y al final lo resolví, después cuelgo mi solución.
Creo que para la gente que empieza no esta al 100% clara la documentación, echo en falta más y diversos ejemplos, que sean completos [ models, views, urls ] y claro tener algún maestro del código cerca también ayuda.
Ya sabéis una documentación for dummies! jejeje

Answer (score 0):

Vale yo mismo me respondo, ya que encontré la solución varias horas después, y si, gracias a la documentación releída varias veces, por falta de entendimiento ya que al ser novato eloqhay!. XD

Creamos una clase llamada StandardResultsSetPagination, donde diremos la paginación que queremos.

```
class StandardResultsSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 20
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 100
```

- Importamos el módulo:

  from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination
- Desde la clase PredioList(la que nos muestra los resultados) llamamos a la clase de paginar para que "pagine" según le digamos.

Aquí el ejemplo de lo que hice y me funciono.(solo cambie el fichero API.PY(views de mi API)

api.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render
from .models.predio import Predio
from .serializers import PredioSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination


class StandardResultsSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 20
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 100


class PredioList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Predio.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PredioSerializer
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        refcat = self.request.query_params.get('refcat')
        return Predio.objects.filter(refcat__startswith=refcat)
```

Y wala! ya funciona a la perfección.